# Android - how to display alert dialog box with the following condition?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to notify user with alert dialog that user "couldn't be playing this application again cause the application is ideal for too long". (Example : User plays the application, and suddenly user went to sleep and forget to close the application. And if user looks back to the phone, there would appear a alert dialog that told the user couldn't be playing again)

Comment: post here what u have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should try onstop() method.When onstop() method calls start the time and when onresume() method calls stop the time. Now you get the starting time and ending time.Get Difference between the time and if it is greater than the time show dialog box(Which is pretty easy) otherwise no dialog box.